# Identifying the Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $[a,b),-\infty<a<b<\infty$, form a base, Let $\sigma$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$  such that $\tau\subseteq \sigma$.

Then which of the following is/are true?

$1.$ $\sigma=\tau$ or $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

$2.$ If moreover  $x\mapsto -x$ is continuos for $\sigma$ then it is discrete topology.

$3.$ If moreover  $x\mapsto -x$ is homeomorphism for $\sigma$ then it is discrete topology.

$4$. If moreover  $x\mapsto |x|$ is is a homemorphism for $\sigma$ then it is discrete topology.
could any one tell me how to attack this kind of problem? just revising old topology stuffs.

Comment: I see a list of four assertions, but no problem. What is the problem you are trying to attack?

Comment: @Chris. The assertions... Btw, (3) is an immediate consequence of (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Consider the topology $\sigma$ for which $\tau\cup\big\{\{0\}\big\}$ is a base.
2. Let $f(x)=-x$ for $x\in\Bbb R$, and assume that $f$ is continuous. For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $U_x=[-x,-x+1)$. What is $f^{-1}[U_x]\cap[x,x+1)$?
3. Every homeomorphism is continuous.
4. Can the map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto|x|$ **ever** be a homeomorphism?